# What TAB completion is triggering the insertion of the include statement for bits/stdc++.h? How can I prevent it?

Tags: c++, vim, libstdc++, youcompleteme, clangd

Sometimes, after some hour of coding, in which I've certainly mashed <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I find out some file containing `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` (which I don't want to use), which means that some TAB-completion triggered that.

Since I discover this after a long time coding (typically when qualifying the change) I don't know which completion trigger that. Any idea which could it be? Furthermore, can I kind of "blacklist" it?

Comment: I've been using YCM for a long time, and I'm pretty sure this isn't something that's enabled by default. Are you sure you didn't add this at some point?

Comment: @cigien, if you mean adding the header, no, I didn't even know of its existence, not to mention that what I describe has not happened just once, but several times, as many as I needed to start checking the headers before submitting a change to make sure that header has not sneaked in.

Comment: Are there any headers that you want to be auto completed? I can't remember how to off the top of my head, but there's definitely a way to disable all of them. There's probably a way to be more fine-grained of course.

Comment: @cigien, I'd say I want all of them except _that_ one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been lucky today while working near the top of a source file. The header `<bits/stdc++.h>` gets included when I <kbd>Tab</kbd>-complete `std::size_t`.